# Swift 2 value extraction from Enum

Tags: swift, enums

Prior to Swift 2, I would often use enums with associated values and add functions to extract specific values, like so:

```
public enum Maybe <T> {
  case Unknown
  case Known(T)

  public var value: T? {
    switch self {
    case .Unknown: return nil
    case .Known(let value): return value
    }
  }
}
```

This would allow me to do something like this:

```
let maybe = .Known("Value")
let val = maybe.value ?? "Another Value"
```

I would like to get rid of these convenience functions and rely on Swift 2's new syntax.  This is possible doing something like:

```
let val: String
if case .Known(let value) = maybe {
  val = value
} else {
  val = "Another Value"
}
```

But I can't figure out how to condense this back into a single line using the `??` operator or even ternary operator.

Is this even possible or am I stuck with defining "extraction" optionals on the enum?

### Update (clarification)

The `Maybe` enum is just an example, but the solution would need to work on Enums that have multiple associated values... like an `Either`:

```
public enum Either<L, R> {
  case Left(Box<L>)
  case Right(Box<R>)

  public func left() -> L?{
    switch self {
    case let Left(value):
      return value.value
    default:
      return nil
    }
  }

  public func right() -> R?{
    switch self {
    case let Right(value):
      return value.value
    default:
      return nil
    }
  }
}
```

The syntax I'm looking for would be something like:

```
let val = (case .Known(let value) = maybe) ?? "AnotherValue"
```

What I want to do is easily extract an associated value for a specific case, else provide a default.

For `Either` it might be something like:

```
let val = (case .Left(let value) = either) ?? "AnotherValue"
```

Make sense?

Comment: Why are you declaring your own `Maybe` type anyways? That's exactly what `Optional`s are for!

Comment: Actually, it's not.  It doesn't conform to `NilLiteralConvertable`.  You might use something like this if you wanted to be explicit about a value's absence or provide more information about why it's missing.

Comment: What syntax you you want to use with this `Either`? Perhaps you want to give the actual example you're trying to solve (since `Either` is also very well explored: https://github.com/robrix/Either). Basically: what do you want to compile that doesn't compile today?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The syntax you want isn't possible in Swift today (and feels unlikely for Swift tomorrow, but I often am surprised). The best available solutions are extraction functions like `left() -> L?` and `right() -> R?`. `case` is not a generic value-returning function that you can extend. See Rob Rix's [`Either`](https://github.com/robrix/Either) for some of the best current thinking on this problem.

A key choice in Swift is that there are many statements that are not expressions. `switch` is one of them. Until Swift makes things like `switch` and `if` be expressions, it will be very hard to build this kind of syntax IMO.

---

Just define `??` for it:

```
func ??<T>(lhs: Maybe<T>, @autoclosure defaultValue: () throws -> T) rethrows -> T {
    switch lhs {
    case .Unknown: return try defaultValue()
    case .Known(let value): return value
    }
}


let maybe = Maybe.Known("Value")

let val = maybe ?? "Another Value"
```

Doing it this way gives us some nice features in Swift2. For instance, we can lazily evaluate the rhs, and we can handle throwing in the rhs:

```
func computeIt() -> String {
    print("LAZY!")
    return "Computed"
}

maybe ?? computeIt() // Does not print "LAZY!"
Maybe.Unknown ?? computeIt() // Does print "LAZY!"

enum Error: ErrorType {
    case Failure
}
func fail() throws -> String {
    throw Error.Failure
}

try maybe ?? fail() // Doesn't throw

do {
    try Maybe.Unknown ?? fail() // throws
} catch {
    print("THROW")
}
```

Comment: That's functionally equivalent to creating a `value` variable and it doesn't actually solve the problem I'm facing... it just moves it to an infix operator.  Moreover, this doesn't help so much if I've got multiple case statements with different values.  I'll update my question to be more specific.

Comment: ok; your question seemed to indicate it was the `value()` function you objected to. I'll be interested in what your actual question is.

Comment: Ok, I tried to update with an actual syntax example.  That syntax doesn't work, obviously but it gives the idea of what I'm trying to accomplish.

Comment: Yeah, I thought this might not be possible, but it would be nice. I checked out Rob's  `Either` and it is almost exactly like my own implementation (I didn't paste the whole thing). I was hoping I might be able to use some kind of functional paradigm to solve the problem but I've got nothing as of yet.